# vmware project clarity and responsive design components for angular

Tags: angular, responsive-design, vmware-clarity

We are looking for angular UI components library, and we found that [project clarity](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/) can cover all needed requirements for our project. But we have one last concern which is the responsiveness. I could not found a clear answer even on their website. So, I want to hear from people who use it before.

Does project clarity have a responsive design components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Project Clarity` is responsive by design. Its components like `datagrid`, `table`, `sidenav` etc are responsive to the screen size and platform. I have used `Project Clarity` for a production software.

Comment: Thank you Soumaya Kanti.

Comment: By the way, does it support RTL?

Comment: As far as I know, not yet. Check this: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1176

Comment: Thanks for your help.